# iOS Charts -> Last value doesn't appear

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, ios-charts

I have some troubles with the library, when I create a barChart I have to add an extra value to my values array in order to show all my original values, and in the lineChart the last value appears in the line graph but it doesn't have its value above the point like the others.

I let you my code and some pictures showing the problem:

**BarChart:** My xAxis have a custom format showing months.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let unitsSold = [20.0, 4.0, 6.0, 3.0, 12.0, 16.0, 4.0, 18.0, 2.0, 4.0, 5.0, 4.0]
    max = unitsSold.maxElement()        

    setChart(unitsSold)        
}


func setChart(values: [Double]) {

    let formato:BarChartFormatter = BarChartFormatter()
    let xaxis:XAxis = XAxis()

    barChartView.noDataText = "You need to provide data for the chart."

    var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []

    for i in 0..<values.count {
        let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y:values[i])
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)

        formato.stringForValue(Double(i), axis: xaxis)
    }

    xaxis.valueFormatter = formato

    let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Units Sold")
    chartDataSet.colors = ChartColorTemplates.joyful()

    barChartView.fitBars = true //Para que las barras inicial y final se muestren completas
    barChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = xaxis.valueFormatter
    barChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .Bottom
    barChartView.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0
    barChartView.leftAxis.axisMaximum = max + 2
    barChartView.rightAxis.enabled = false
    barChartView.drawValueAboveBarEnabled = false
    barChartView.descriptionText = ""
    barChartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    barChartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 1.0, yAxisDuration: 1.0)

    let chartData = BarChartData()
    chartData.addDataSet(chartDataSet)
    barChartView.data = chartData
}
```

**LineChart:** My xAxis have a custom format showing months.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let unitsSold = [20.0, 4.0, 6.0, 3.0, 12.0, 16.0]
    max = unitsSold.maxElement()

    setChart(unitsSold)   
}

func setChart(values: [Double]) {

    let formato:BarChartFormatter = BarChartFormatter()
    let xaxis:XAxis = XAxis()

    var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []

    for i in 0..<values.count {
        let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: values[i])
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)

        formato.stringForValue(Double(i), axis: xaxis)
    }

    xaxis.valueFormatter = formato

    let lineChartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Units Sold")
    lineChartDataSet.colors = ChartColorTemplates.joyful()
    lineChartDataSet.circleColors = ChartColorTemplates.joyful()
    lineChartDataSet.drawCircleHoleEnabled = false


    let lineChartData = LineChartData( dataSet: lineChartDataSet)
    lineChartData.setValueFont(UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 7))

    lineChartView.fitScreen()
    lineChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .Bottom
    lineChartView.xAxis.axisMaximum = Double(values.count) 
    lineChartView.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0
    lineChartView.leftAxis.axisMaximum = max + 3
    lineChartView.rightAxis.enabled = false
    lineChartView.descriptionText = ""
    lineChartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    lineChartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 1.0, yAxisDuration: 1.0)
    lineChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = xaxis.valueFormatter

    lineChartView.data = lineChartData
 }
```

**The responses are:**  For barChart December doesn't appear and in lineChart the last value doesn't show its value above it, I hope someone can help.

[image: BarChart]

[image]

Comment: can you provide the name of libraries which you are using? my quick advise is, add some NSLog to the delegate function of the chart framework classes . For example, there should be methods like cellForRowAtIndexPath or numberOfRowsInSection @ UITableViewDelegate.

Comment: The name was iOS-Charts but now it changed to Charts, this is the library:

https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

Comment: Okay, let me create a project to have a look :D

Comment: https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/1384 - someone answered your question

Comment: Yeah, I create that issue in github and we found a solution for the barChart, but lineChart continues hiding the value for the last value

Comment: @JulioCesarAguilarJiménez what solution you found for this problem i am facing same issue